# Search and delete a string starting with xmlns till double quotes in notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++

Please help me in deleting the string starting with xmlns till the second occurence of " [double quotes] as shown. File contains multiple lines and for this example i have taken two lines

```
<retrievedItems xmlns="http://www.wnco.com/retrievehistory/v2">

<dataelements xmlns="http://www.wnco.com/dataelements/v2"/>
```

After replacing it should be as below

```
<retrievedItems>

<dataelements/>
```

Comment: your post is not compleet (and unclear to me), please show us en be more specific

Comment: and what kind of editor do you use / have?

Comment: Sorry i was using "<" symbol but it was not displaying now replaced it with flower braacket. I am using notepad++

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression is the way for you!

replace

```
xmlns=\".+?\"
```

with nothing :)

Look [here](http://regex101.com/r/kI4lX4) to see /  test the regex

Comment: There are thousands of lines, for example i have taken just two lines

Comment: good to hear, regex are pretty powerfull for text manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression: `xmlns\:.+?=\".+?\"`

This will also account for `xmlns:namespace="<URL>"`